# VBA Automate IE: element.click and element.FireEvent (OnClick) Not working

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, automation, html-parsing

I am trying to parse a web based pivot table. 
Unfortunately, I need to expand additional lines in the web based pivot table in order to access all the data I need. I think that when I click on the + sign to expand additional lines, a script downloads the additional data from the database.

Anyway, here is the html code of the + sign:

```html
<DIV class="clip9x9 di-img" onclick=_Ewa.Gim.tpdfce(event);>
    <INPUT title=Expand class=ewaboot_expand type=image alt=Expand src="http://...">
</DIV>
```

I manage to get the correct element into an variable using `IE.document.getElementsByTagName("Div")` and a If Loop (for some reason the `GetElementByClassName` would crash my IE), but none of the `.Click` or `.FireEvent (OnClick)` methods works. I also tried both methods on the Input element below the `DIV`, and these are not working either. 
Here is the code

```
Sub Test()
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Dim div As Variant
    Dim Obj As Variant
    Dim WebUrl As String

    WebUrl = "http://..../filename.aspx"
    Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
    Sleep 1000
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate WebUrl
    Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Sleep 1000
    Loop

    Set div = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("Div")

    For Each Obj In div
        If Obj.className = "clip9x9 di-img" Then
            Obj.Click
            Obj.FireEvent ("OnClick")
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

When I look at the onclick attribute of my Obj element in th Spy Window (VBA editor), the onclick property has a + sign aside, and when inspecting inside it, no variable is attributed to it. I find it weird since the HTML code indicates a `value =”_Ewa.Gim.tpdfce(event);”` which I believe refers to the script that expands the pivot table line.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Can you share the URL? Or at least the html that is relevant. It is also possible an element is created on the fly. You also declare as InternetExplorer but then Set as New InternetExplorerMeduim. Use one or the other.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot share the URL. It is an intranet URL requiring credentials.

Comment: <DIV class="clip9x9 di-img" onclick=”_Ewa.Gim.tpdfce(event);”>
          <INPUT title=Expand class=ewaboot_expand type=image alt=Expand src="http://.../images/..."></DIV>

Comment: For some reason the HTML code above did not appear in my original question. I hope this might help

Comment: Does it really have the ”   ? I wonder if that has been changed from " during copy paste. In this part:  onclick=”_Ewa.Gim.tpdfce(event);”  should it be  onclick="_Ewa.Gim.tpdfce(event);"

Comment: Actually the " appears only in the DOM Explorer in IE. When I copied-pasted the code, the " was not appearing. Here is the code

Comment: <DIV class="clip9x9 di-img" onclick=_Ewa.Gim.tpdfce(event);><INPUT title=Expand class=ewaboot_expand type=image alt=Expand src="http://..."></DIV>

Comment: you might want to look into creating a keyboard event and seeing if you can use InitEvent even though deprecated someone in last few days posted an answer saying that worked for them by creating an event and then firing it.